# Transparent picturebox flickers

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, picturebox

So I'm coding a project that is Plants vs. Zombies made of pure c# using no game engines and here I have a graphic problem.
I need to render a transparent picturebox over another transparent picturebox and I had to define a new control that is really transparent and everything goes fine with the transparency aspect but here is a problem:
Flicker :|
I have so much of them because of the RecreateHandle(); method I use when I change the image of my control to make animations and when it moves to have the real transparency.
Here is my code I wonder if any one could help !

```
public class TransparentControl : Control
{
    private Image _image;

    public TransparentControl()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
             ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        base.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        //RecreateHandle();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_image != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, (Width / 2) - (_image.Width / 2), (Height / 2) - (_image.Height / 2));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do not paint background
    }

    //Hack
    public void Redraw()
    {
        //RecreateHandle();
    }
    public Image Image
    {
        get
        {
            return _image;
        }
        set
        {
            _image = value;
            //RecreateHandle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DoubleBuffer the drawing container and don't use controls.  Draw everything.

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce flickering is to create two different bitmaps. One to draw to, and one to display.

```
Image BackBuffer;
Image BrontBuffer;

private void RotateImages()
{
    lock (this.BackBuffer)
    {
        var temp = this.BackBuffer;
        this.BackBuffer = this.FrontBuffer;
        this.FrontBuffer = temp;
    }
}
```

Draw **everything** into your BackBuffer, then show the FrontBuffer.

Note that you should declare the FrontBuffer with the same width/height values as the BackBuffer, in pretty much exactly the same spot that you declare the BackBuffer.

Use the method `RotateImages()` immediately after (*before should work, too*) you display the front buffer.

Comment: Im a bit "noob" at graphics. so how can I add it in my control? : /

Comment: The best advice is probably to follow what @LarsTech says and stop using controls altogether. Draw everything.